# float split Attribute error in python 2

Tags: python

I am relatively new in python, hence decided to learn python3. But, now, I realize, that is not implemented in many other machine. So, I need to change it, for python2. In the machine in question, we have:

```
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Sep 27 2013, 16:07:59)
```

So, I am facing a problem of transfering this part:

```
beta = []
inb = input("Betah\n")
if inb == "/":
    betah = "0.1 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 5.0 10.0 15.0 20.0 25.0 200.0"
else:
    betah = inb
beta = betah.split(" ")
```

which is giving error:

```
beta = betah.split(" ")
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

is it possible to write this part so that it works both in `python2` and `3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3's `input()` is called [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) in Python 2; use the latter on Python 2.

Assign either name to a new one based on what is available:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    userinput = raw_input
except NameError:
    # Python 3
    userinput = input

inb = userinput("Betah\n")
```